# Lotus Notes 8.5.3 applications not displaying correctly

Tags: 11.10, notes

When using custom Lotus 8.5.3 applications on Ubuntu 11.10, I'm finding that they don't display correctly.  The viewing pane is half white and half blue, however, Notes appears to load other applications, such as Mail, correctly.

This seems to describe the issue that I'm having on older version - https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21409777

Has anyone seen or fixed this issue?

I'm using 32-bit Ubuntu 11.10, with Notes 8.5.3 on a VM (VMware Player).

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar issue (part of the solution is here) on my laptop (not VM)

The libnotesgtkfix.so  to me is the solution (all other parts are for 64bits version)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1864573

Comment: Can you please link to the specific fix? Sending someone to read a huge thread isn't much help.